# Как располагать элементы в одной ячейке grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы три картинки по середине располагались друг за другом. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, надо что бы картинки занимали 1,2,3 ячейки. Если так, то для 3 картинки укажи grid-column: 3/4 . Если же вопрос в том, как сделать картинки на всю площадь контейнера, то тут 2 варианта:
1.Картинка объявлена в теге img: для контейнера добавь стили width:100%; height: 100%;, а для картинки width:100%; object-fit: cover;.
2.Картинка объявлена в background: для background добавь стиль background-size: cover;: